# How can we place standard Quick Actions in a Custom Activity Timeline component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, winter17

With Winter '17, the Activity Timeline component of SLDS has been improved to also include `Quick Actions` like (*Log a Call*, *New Task*, *New Event*). Earlier it only showed the Activity Timeline view.

**Winter '17:**

[image]

**Earlier:**

[image]

I had initially built a component that replaced the Activity Timeline on the layout in Lightning Experience, but I now need to include the newest addition of Quick Actions to the Timeline component. Because the standard Activity component from `Lightning App Builder` now automatically include these actions, and there is no seperate component just to put these on top of the Timeline component.

Is there a way I can include them in via Code?